# How to find subjects which are bound to a certain location (sparql)

Tags: sparql, geosparql

Currently, I am trying to find subjects in which case the **geo:asWKT** is the same for all these subjects in the [Dutch sparql endpoint](https://data.pdok.nl/sparql). Initially I derived the geo:asWKT from a building and subsequently I tried to have corresponding **subjects** to this location (such as licenses or other information of the buildings which are tied to this location/building.

I assumed by writing the following sparql query, that I would be able to retrieve the subjects which are bound to a certain location, however I don't receive any results back. I am not sure whether this is due

1. to my query or
2. whether there are simply no results to return to.

I am a beginner to SPARQL, so I might have formulated the query too simply, but I assumed when I use the ***?Gebouwgeo*** in the two lines of the **SELECT** clause, it will have the same value for the ***?Gebouwgeo*** in the two lines and when I assign a question word (***?y*** in my case) as a subject, it will give all possible subjects

So I am not sure whether it is due to my query or if it's possible that the query can't be made: I learnt that much data in the Dutch SPARQL endpoint are not yet connected to each other, so it might be probable that these linkages haven't been made yet and therefore these kind of queries might not possibly be queried yet in the Dutch Sparql endpoint.

```
PREFIX top10nl: <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#>
PREFIX brt: <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX uom: <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/>

SELECT  ?y ?Gebouwgeo where { VALUES ?s {<http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/top10nl/id/gebouw/102572805>}
  ?s geo:hasGeometry/geo:asWKT ?Gebouwgeo.
  ?y geo:asWKT ?Gebouwgeo.
}
```

Comment: The query is correct, or better said there is most likely only the single result. But honestly, right now you're trying to find objects with exactly the same polygon. How should this work? It should be impossible for other buildings to have the same polygon, shouldn't it? Is this clear to you what this means? You should use GeoSPARQL functions if the endpoints supports this

Comment: @AKSW I will try to explain my line of thought. Pardon me, if my line of thought doesn't make any sense at all. The idea is that I assume that certain type of information is bound to a certain building/location (such as this building is built for example in 1923). I would like to retrieve all those kind of information which I assume is tied to a certain location. However when I think about it, in the prefix, the information is currently only from BRT, so I am not sure how I should retrieve info from other datasets, if I don't know beforehand from where the data will be retrieved :(.

Comment: @AKSW  I am currently not using the geosparql endpoint, since there is currently no data available in the geosparql endpoint. However when I do geosparql queries in the normal sparql endpoint, in another of my question of stackoverflow, which you were able to help me :), I still received results. So I assume that for some reason geosparql queries are still possible to conduct in the 'normal' sparql endpoint, which I don't quite understand.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "geosparql endpoint" - GeoSPARQL is more or less an extension of SPARQL for geospatial data. If the SPARQL endpoint - or to be more precise the triple store in the backend - supports GeoSPARQL, everything is fine. So it looks like the endpoint you used just supports GeoSPARQL

Comment: Regarding the current question, I have to think about it again. Not sure if I understand it: we have a house for which we have some geodata in forms of a polygon. So why should some other information be connected to the polygon? Do I miss something here? The relation is most likely `object --hasGeoData--> geoData` or not? And in addition of course the object has other properties like I don't know, color, height, whatever (if we're talking about houses) - so what is your query supposed to do?

Comment: @AKSW, the provider of the Linked Data PDOK have made two sparql endpoints available, in which one is 'normal' without geosparql functionalities ,while there is a geosparql endpoint which should enable geosparql functionalities. This is stated on the website of the provider of the data and sparql endpoints https://data.labs.pdok.nl/ So that's why I assumed that there are two seperate sparql endpoints :)

Comment: @AKSW In regards to your last point, I guess I have to explain my background a little bit. I do follow a Geographic Information Systems study and during my study I do mostly GIS analysis.  In GIS analysis the base are in fact coordinate systems and therefore locations, which make it possible to stack layers on top of each other and do analysis on top of these layers to find the relevant information. Therefore,I am inclined to assume that locations are the binding factors between different type of information ( which might not necessarily be the case in the field of Linked Data.

Comment: ok, but if we go back to the example building in your query, we have a single polygon that describes its geographical location, right? So I still don't understand how any other object should be related in the graph to the same polygon. That's why I though you mean more some other relationship like intersects the polygon, or is close to the polygon. But yeah, I'm not a domain expert nor a GIS expert. I just cannot imagine that the is one object with a polygon and then another object with the same polygon. And as far is I understand, the relation here is `object has polygon`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190290/discussion-between-joy-and-aksw).